# Add different data to a specific cell in google sheet

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, python-requests

I would like to create a table in a google sheet with different type of data : **title/string (in A1 : "Clients Indépendants") > string ("A2" : "Montant") > number ("B2" : '43766468' linked to a variable)/ "A5" : an empty cell.** Example:
[image]

I can create a new sheet and my variable which contains a filter and a formula works. However I don’t succeed to add different type of data in the same sheet.
Here the body request :

```
request_body6 = {
        "requests" : [
            {
                "updateCells": {
                    "rows" : {
                        "values" : [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue" :
                                    {
                                    "stringValue": 'Clients indépendant',
                                    "stringValue": 'Montant',
                                    "numberValue": montant_total_independants,
                                    "stringValue": 'Nb clients',
                                    "numberValue": nombre_client_independants,
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "start" : {
                    "sheetId" : id_new_sheet6, 
                    "rowIndex" : 0, 
                    "columnIndex" : 0
                    },
                    "fields" : "userEnteredValue"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here the error :

```
'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_cells.rows.values[0].user_entered_value' (oneof), oneof field 'value' is already set. Cannot set 'numberValue'"}]}]">
```

Do you have any ideas how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws an error because you are trying to pass multiple entries into a single cell. `userEnteredValue` should only hold one value, the others being other elements of the `values` list. Assuming you want to populate `A1`, `A2` and `B2`, schematically your request object should look like this:

```py
{"rows" : [{"values":[{A1}, {A2}]}, {"values": [{},{B2}]}]}
```

And in your specific case:

```py
"rows" : [
  {"values":[
    {"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue": 'Clients indépendant'}},
    {"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue": 'Montant'}},
  ]},
  {"values":[
    {},
    {"userEnteredValue":{"numberValue": montant_total_independants}},
  ]}
]
```

You can find the relevant documentation on how to structure such requests [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest).